# Created Hashed Password in PHP Class

Tags: php, oop, hashcode, password-encryption

So I'm trying to create a Blowfish encrypted password with a salt using a User class that I have created, which in turns extends an overall database object that uses Late Static Bindings to CRUD from my database. Anyway, I'm trying to get this darn thing to encrypt the password before I call the create() method and inset it onto my database but each time when I do put the information in the form it goes to a blank 'update.php' screen (update.php has all my isset($_POST[]) calls for all my forms) and nothing gets uploaded to my database. Here's the code so far...

### Code in update.php

```
if (isset($_POST["createAdmin"])) {

    $user = new Users();
    $user->password = $user->password_encrypt($_POST['new_password']);
    $user->username = $_POST['new_username'];
    $user->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $user->last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    if($user->create()) {
        $_SESSION['new_admin_message'] = $user->password;
        redirect_to("../public/admin/manage_admin.php");
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['new_admin_message'] ="Admin didn't create successfully";
        redirect_to("../public/admin/manage_admin.php");
    }
}
```

### Code in user.php (the user class)

```
<?php
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'database.php');

class Users extends DatabaseObject {


    protected static $table_name="users";
    protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name');
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

public static function password_encrypt($password) {
    $hashed_format = "2y$10$"; // Tels PHP to use Blowfish with a "cost" of 10
    $salt_length = 22; // Blowfish salts should be 22-characters or more
    $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt; 
    $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
    return $hash;
}

private function generate_salt($length) {
    // Not 100% unique, not 100% random, but good enoguh for a salt 
    // MD5 returns 32 characters
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    // Valid caracters for a solt are [a-zA-Z0-9./]
    $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);

    // But not '+' which is valid in base64 encoding
    $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+', ".", $base64_string);

    //Truncate string to the correct length
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);

    return $salt;
}
```

There's a couple other methods in the class that aren't important for this particular problem. I'm relatively new to OOP and PHP in general so any help would be greatly appreciated. If you could leave a short description on how you fixed the problem that would be awesome too. Thanks!!

Comment: If you're above php5.5 I strongly recommend using the `password_hash` function. If you're not, but still above 5.3.7, the same can be achieved with [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Yeah I think I'll do that, I need to upgrade my PHP first.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things wrong with your code:

1. You cannot refer to a normal method from a static method. In order for your code to work you also have to make the `generate_salt` method `static`.
2. You use the wrong format variable (`$hash_format` should be `$hashed_format`) when concatenating the format and salt.
3. Your format is wrong. Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/crypt). The blowfish format is:

   ```
   $[algo]$[difficulty]$[salt]$
   ```

   Your format comes out to be:

   ```
   [algo]$[difficulty]$[salt]
   ```

So, change your method to something like this:

```
public static function password_encrypt($password) {
    $format = '$2y$10$'.$this->generate_salt(22).'$';
    return crypt($password, $format);
}
```

Another thing, which is not technically "wrong" but is not a good thing, is your salt method. You should generate your salt from a cryptographically stronger source, such as using the `mcrypt` extension or, if you are on *nix, even grabbing it from /urandom or /random. Creating a "random" string by calling a mish-mash of functions, and ending up with something that *looks random enough*, is not a good idea.

**The best thing you could do** is to use the [`password` library](http://php.net/password) that comes with PHP. It will handle all the password hashing for you, and will protect you from yourself. If you have PHP <5.5.0 then you should use the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

In other words, you should change your code to this:

```
public static function password_encrypt($password) {
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);
}
```

Comment: Im using PHP 5.4.10 so I think I'll just upgrade it and follow your advice above. I think it should work once I upgrade, I'll let you know. I don't suppose you know how to upgrade PHP versions on MAMP Pro V 2x ? I'm having the hardest time finding any answers on how to do it, even on their site...

Comment: I would just use the compatibility library. It does the same thing, and it is a lot easier than upgrading your MAMP server.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah it's a pain trying to find how to upgrade PHP with MAMP - I think I'll use the library. Do you know if the library conflicts with new versions of PHP?